# What are the legal and illegal characters in URL/Link?

Tags: url, hyperlink, web

What happens if there is a illegal character? Does the URL fix it self by encoding the illegal characters into something else?

Answer (score 8):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547940/2669716)

> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=.
>   Any other character needs to be encoded with the percent-encoding
>   (%hh). Each part of the URI has further restrictions about what
>   characters need to be represented by an percent-encoded word.

Answer (score 4):

#### Allowed characters

[RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) defines which characters are allowed in which URI components.

RFCs for specific [URI schemes](http://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes) might further restrict this.

If you are interested in HTTP/HTTPS URIs: they are defined in [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). AFAIK they don’t have further restrictions regarding allowed characters, so you could stick to the definitions in RFC 3986.

#### What happens if illegal characters are used?

Depends on many factors … could be anything from "nothing happens" to "doesn’t work anymore".

> Does the URL fix it self by encoding the illegal characters into something else?

A URI can’t fix itself, it’s just a string.

Clients working with this URI (browser, server, email client, etc.) *may* try to fix a URI (or work with invalid URIs) according to their own rules.

#### URI vs. link

Also note that there’s a difference between a URI and linking to (or storing etc.) this URI in a document.
The host language (e.g., HTML) might have rules what to encode. This does *not* change the URI, only the way the URI is stored/specified in this document.

For example, the valid URI `http://example.com/a&b` would have to be linked like this in HTML documents:

```html
<a href="http://example.com/a&amp;b">Link</a>
```

But the URI is still `http://example.com/a&b`, not `http://example.com/a&amp;b`.