# HTML validation generates error

Tags: html, css, fonts, w3c-validation

I am using google fonts and it generates following error for below link

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic|Roboto+Condensed|Source+Sans+Pro|Droid+Serif|Open+Sans+Condensed|Oswald|Molengo|PT Sans|Droid Sans')" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> **Line 35, Column 289:** Bad value for attribute `href` on element `link`: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.
>
> ```
> …if|Open+Sans+Condensed|Oswald|Molengo|PT Sans|Droid Sans')" rel="stylesheet" />
> ```
>
> Syntax of URL:
>           Any URL. For example: /hello, #canvas, or http://example.org/. Characters should be represented in NFC and spaces should be escaped as %20.

SAMPLE HTML

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic|Roboto+Condensed|Source+Sans+Pro|Droid+Serif|Open+Sans+Condensed|Oswald|Molengo|PT+Sans|Droid+Sans')" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE

**This generates error**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%20Condensed|Source%20Sans%20Pro" />
```

**This Works**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato"  />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto%20Condensed" />
```

When i add `|` to add multiple fonts it generates error so should i use multiple `<link>` tag to add fonts or ?

Confused about this is as below links is generate by on Google fonts font use on website

```
https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Open+Sans|Roboto:400,700,400italic|Roboto+Condensed:400,300|Lato
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your example code working with JAVASCRIPT NOTATION**
LINK and IMPORT may not help to eliminate the VALIDATION error - so please try with JAVASCRIPT notation it works well without any error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
WebFontConfig = {google: { families: [ Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic|Roboto+Condensed|Source+Sans+Pro|Droid+Serif|Open+Sans+Condensed|Oswald|Molengo|PT+Sans|Droid+Sans ] }};
(function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**You will need to substiture `&` sign with `&amp;`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&amp;subset=latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You may please use JAVASCRIPT notation for including the fonts from google

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: { families: [ 'Open+Sans::cyrillic-ext,latin,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese,latin-ext,cyrillic' ] }
  };
  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
      '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })(); </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Few more suggestions

1. Always include doctype at the top of HTML page
2. Try the IMPORT and JAVASCRIPT alternatives to include the fonts.
3. Please use your own google font - to avoid typos I tried with new fonts from google.

Comment: How will you add multiple fonts?

Comment: I have updated the answer - please check first section of the answer. With javascript notation it doesn't give any error.

Comment: @Learning There is no need for any of that. All it does is give you what you want in a different fashion, with javascript, rather than fix what you have. And what happens should the js fail in some way? Don't do this.

Answer (score 3):

The character `|` is [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30412617/1591669) in the [query component](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66#section-3.4) (nor anywhere else in a URI). It would have to be percent-encoded with `%7C`.

So

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic|Roboto+Condensed|Source+Sans+Pro|Droid+Serif|Open+Sans+Condensed|Oswald|Molengo|PT+Sans|Droid+Sans')
```

should be this URI instead

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic%7CMontserrat:700%7CMerriweather:400italic%7CRoboto+Condensed%7CSource+Sans+Pro%7CDroid+Serif%7COpen+Sans+Condensed%7COswald%7CMolengo%7CPT+Sans%7CDroid+Sans')
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a space in the string near the end

```
PT Sans|Droid Sans')"
```

should be escaped as:

```
PT%20Sans|Droid%20Sans')"
```

Comment: Changing it to `    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic|Montserrat:700|Merriweather:400italic|Roboto%20Condensed|Source%20Sans%20Pro|Droid%20Serif|Open%20Sans%20Condensed|Oswald|Molengo|PT%20Sans|Droid%20Sans')"  />` generates same error

Comment: Can you add the new error as a screenshot next to the first one?