# How to Encode '/' in ASP.NET MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Tool(string id)
{
  // Code goes here . . 
}
```

View:

```
<a href="/Home/@item.Type/@Url.Encode(item.Title)" id="toolTitleLink">@item.Title</a>
```

From the code above `@item.Title` can have special characters like '/' sample link is `http://localhost:39727/Home/Tool/C+Compiler+For+The+Pic10%2f12%2f16+Mcus` when I try to navigate to that link `Tool Controller` was not called. I used `@Url.Encode` but still `Controller` was not called.

Comment: You can catch all symbols in **id** after */Home/Tool/* part with catchall route. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6328758/1770952)

Comment: Thanks @IvanGritsenko It works but I want to apply it to multiple Action, do I need to create Custom Route for each action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately even if you use [`System.Uri.EscapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Url.Encode` like so:

```
<a href="/Home/@item.Type/@System.Uri.EscapeDataString(item.Title)" id="toolTitleLink">@item.Title</a>
```

The rendered page will have the slashes encoded (look in the 'view source' of the page) the browser will still decode them.

You have two options, as far as I can see:

1. Use a different character - make your own escape (so to speak ;)) - for example using tilda (~) or whatever else [URL valid character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30402168/1796) you want, in order to replace the forward slash.
2. Create a special route for the action with [a catch-all at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6328758/1796) and parse things from the action.